# show download link if file already uploaded or show file upload field in gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a form created by gravity forms which will allow the user to enter the data and upload two files (form has two input file fields - gravity forms provided file upload field). Once the user submit the page, I will save the data in to custom table with file path as one of the column inside the table.

But once form reloads, it will show the same form with already entered data, but don't know how to show the file link inside the form.

What I am trying to do is, I have to show the link with remove button if file already uploaded or show the file upload field again to allow user to upload the file again.

Could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you will store the entered data on the custom table, store the file names as well.
Then have another function to check if the file is in the specified directory (ex. uploads).

This is a lazy solution, so keep an eye on your thread for a better one.

Comment: when I am using gravity forms file upload, and user clicked on submit button, the file was already uploaded to the server and getting the full link in gform_after_submission hook and saving in the respective table column.

what I don't know is how to show the gravity forms file upload field if there is no file upload and if file existing show link with remove button while using gform_pre_render hook.  If possible could you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not using gravity forms file upload field as even sent mail with priority support asking for is there any hook to know when user clicked "X" button of uploaded file(this will be shown once user clicks on submit button after uploading the file), but they replied, they don't support customization and pointed to 3rd party developers.

So what I did is, removed file upload field and used html field, which I am showing manual file upload (html input type file) field if no file uploaded or showing the file link with remove button. This remove button handled via javascript which will update some hidden field and after submit I know user removed the file or not.